# Problem associating a kernel to a virtual environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I'm using anaconda on a remote server for a project.

After having setup a new environment with

```
conda create -n myenv
```

I install everything I need there, e.g. `tensorflow`. If I try to use python on cmd (e.g. trying to import installed packages), everyhting works fine, for example

```
import tensorflow
```

runs smoothly. The problem arises when I try to create a *Jupyter* kernel based on the environment I have created. I simply do

```
ipython kernel install --name myenv --user
```

then opening a new notebook choosing `myenv` kernel but trying

```
import tensorflow
```

returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Am I missing anything? What is the precise relation between virtual environments and kernels?

Comment: Did you run `ipython kernel install --name myenv --user` while the `myenv` was active? What does `import sys` followed by `sys.executable` give you when run in your jupyter notebook with the `myenv` kernel?

Comment: actually no, I've done the ipython kernel install with my base environment specifying the name of desired env.. Also sys.exectuable returns /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: Thank you  very much the problem was actually doing ipython kernel install by having activated the environment before. In fact, my doubt was that ipython was not recognized in myenv but I had to simply install it

Comment: Yes exactly. The `--name myenv` to `ipython kernel install` is any arbitrary name that you give to this new kernel. It is not aware of any conda envs unless you activate them first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the environment before installing the kernel, so

```
conda activate myenv
ipython kernel install --name myenv --user
```

the `--name myenv` argument to `ipython` just specifies the name of the new kernel in the kernel drop down menu of your jupyter notebooks